# Draw a Golden Spiral!

Tags: code-golf, math, graphical-output

Given a number `n`, you must output a [golden spiral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_spiral) with the number of quarter turns being `n`.

The spiral must be completely black and the background must be completely white. This must be output as a φ<sup>⌊n/4⌋*4</sup> by φ<sup>⌊n/4⌋*4</sup> PNG file (you may output a PPM and convert it later). The shortest code wins.

The radius of the smallest quarter turn should be φ<sup>-3</sup>.

In geometry, a golden spiral is a logarithmic spiral whose growth factor is φ, the golden ratio.That is, a golden spiral gets wider (or further from its origin) by a factor of φ for every quarter turn it makes.

Comment: So, this is actually `Draw a black golden spiral` then?

Comment: @Compass You should draw it with coffee or oil, probably, but there are [other options.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_gold)

Comment: @Geobits Just don't use [Marmite](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=am6fco14Gi0)

Comment: If someone was to use blockly, would they have to screen-shot their code?  How would byte-count be decided?  For the curious, the turtle is shown drawing what looks at a glance like the golden spiral: https://blockly-demo.appspot.com/static/apps/index.html?lang=en

Comment: @Will That's not a golden spiral in the icon, it's not even a logarithmic spiral. It's an arithmetic/archimedian spiral (that grows by the same *amount* each revolution.) A golden spiral is a type of logarithmic spiral (that grows by the same *ratio* each revolution.) Another characteristic of a logarithmic spiral is that for any point on the spiral there is a constant angle between the radius passing through that point and the spiral itself, so the spiral looks the same when you zoom in or out. I can't get the blockly sample program to run, though.

Comment: What do the `⌊` and `⌋` mean in the exponent of the height and width? Can they just be read as `(` and `)`?

Comment: @britishtea They resemble the flooring function. Similarly, if they are the other way round, they resemble the ceiling function.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Mathematica, 169 bytes

All those annoying options. :(

```
f=Export[p=GoldenRatio;"a.png",ParametricPlot[p^(2t-3){Cos[a=t*Pi],Sin@a},{t,0,#/2},PlotRange->{r={m=-p^(#-3),-m},r},PlotStyle->Black,Axes->1<0,ImageSize->p^#~Floor~4]]&
```

This function saves the spiral to `a.png` in wherever your current working directory is.

The result of `f[9]`:

[image]

The result of `f[12]`:

[image]

I hope I understood all the bits about the scaling correctly.

There's not a whole lot to say about the code. I'm using `ParametricPlot` to draw curve as a parameterised function in `t` which advances by `1/2` for each quarter turn. The rest is done in the options:

- `PlotRange->{r={m=-p^(#-3),-m},r}` makes sure we have an square aspect ratio which *just* covers the outermost point of the spiral.
- `PlotStyle->Black` overwrites Mathematica's blue default colour.
- `Axes->1<0` is just `Axes->False` (and turns off the axes, who knew!).
- `ImageSize->p^#~Floor~4` sets the correct dimensions in pixels, by noticing that `⌊n/4⌋*4` just means "`n` rounded down to the nearest multiple of `4`".

Comment: Hmm... I think it could perhaps be slightly shorter as a PolarPlot, but it probably wouldn't differ too much.

Comment: @Tally Ah, I keep forgetting about PolarPlot. I'll have a look at that later.

Comment: What? Mathematica doesn't have GoldenSpiral[]? I'm dissapoint

Answer (score 7):

## Python 3 - <strike>290</strike> 269

This will get crushed by any kind of built-in parametrics, but I figured I'd post it as an example of a point-by-point solution.

Edit: Thanks for the golfing tips! If you have any more, please make them.

```
from math import *
from PIL import Image as I, ImageDraw as D
n=eval(input())
G=(1+5**.5)/2
w=int(G**(4*(n//4)))
i=I.new("RGB",(w,w),"white")
d=D.Draw(i)
k=pi/180
d.line([(G**(j/90)*cos(j*k)+w/2,G**(j/90)*sin(j*k)+w/2)for j in range(n*90)],fill=0)
i.save("s.png","PNG")
```

Comment: You can *really* golf this down.  You can `from math import *` to avoid the `M.` prefix everywhere and you can turn the for loop into a comprehension.  However, when I run this, I had to remove the `eval()` on the `input()` for entering a number, and I couldn't get the expected graph for the size.  Setting `n` to a big number like 10 or 20 and it never finishes; setting it to a bigger number like 50 and it immediately aborts because the numbers are too big.

Comment: Thanks for the tips, Will! I'm not sure how to make it work for large n, as the requirements specify an exponential image size.

Comment: You can create your image like so if you only use B&W : `i=I.new('L',(w,w))` and display it with `i.show()`.

Comment: Can shave off two bytes by changing `from math import *` to `from math import*` and `from PIL import Image as I, ImageDraw as D` to `from PIL import Image as I,ImageDraw as D`